# How to export solr result into a text file?

Tags: solr, export

I needs to export `doc_id`, all fields, `socr`, rank of one search result to evaluate the results. How can I do this in solr?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solr provides you with a [CSV Response writer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CSVResponseWriter), which will help you to export the results of solr in an csv file.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=ipod&fl=id,cat,name,popularity,price,score&wt=csv
```

All the fields queried would be returned by Solr in proper format.

Comment: When I set para &fl= *, it just gives me some empty fields which actually contain matches in the query. Is this related to the para "stored"/"indexed" of the fields in the schema.xml?

Comment: fl=* should return all the stored fields in your collection. And depending upon the query columns may or may not hold values.

Comment: How can I control the search only happen in certain field against query?

Comment: You can create queries in normal pattern. If you need againts specific field use q=specific_field:search_term

Comment: How can I rank one document with matches in different fields with all fields searchable. Thank you.

Comment: you can boost your matches on fields. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_make_.22superman.22_in_the_title_field_score_higher_than_in_the_subject_field

Comment: addition to the answer - the query param ``&wt=`` supports all of ``csv``, ``json``, ``xml``. If this is not given - the default format is ``xml``. (y)

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with SOLR. When you make a SOLR query over http, then SOLR does the search and returns the results to you in your desired format. The default is XML but lots of  people specify wt=json to get results in json format. If you want this result in a text file, then make your search client put it there.

In the browser, File -> Save As.

But most people who want this use `curl` as the client and use the `-o` option like this:

```
curl -o result1.xml 'http://solr.local:8080/solr/stuff/select?indent=on&version=2.2&q=fish&fq=&start=0&rows=10&fl=*%2Cscore&qt=&wt=&explainOther=&hl.fl='
```

Note the single quotes around the URL due to the use of & characters.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built in export function in Solr. The easiest way would be to query your Solr instance and evaluate the XML result. Check out [Querying Data in the Solr Tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html#Querying+Data) for details on how to query a result from Solr. In order to convert the result into a text file, I would recommend using one of the Solr Clients found on the [Integrating Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr) page in the Solr Wiki and then choose your programming language of choice to create the text file.